# How to index a Queue with tuples in C#

Tags: c#

I have the following List of Tuples NAME,ID,YOB i Queue them,however when i de-queue i don't know how to index them like i index List with List.item1

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var Name_ID_YOB = new List<Tuple<string,int,int>>(); // YOB is year of birth
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Name_ID_YOB.Add(new Tuple<string, int,int>("Name", i,1998+i));
        }
        Queue MyQueue = new Queue();
        foreach (var tuple in Name_ID_YOB)
        {
            MyQueue.Enqueue(tuple);
        }
        int Total = MyQueue.Count; // Total Item In Queue
        while (MyQueue.Count > 0)
        {
            var NAMEIDYOB = MyQueue.Dequeue();
            Console.WriteLine($"[Console] {NAMEIDYOB}");
            Console.WriteLine($"[Console] {NAMEIDYOB.item1}"); // Expected to print Name
            Console.WriteLine($"[Console] {NAMEIDYOB.item2}"); // Expected to print ID
            Console.WriteLine($"[Console] {NAMEIDYOB.item3}"); // Expected to print YOB
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Dequeue Done");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }   
}
```

Comment: Please explain what did you try and what didn't work for you.

Answer (score 2):

Use Generic Queue as you do with List:

`var MyQueue = new Queue<Tuple<string,int,int>>();`

Also you need to start `Item1`, `Item2`, `Item3` with capital letters:

```
while (MyQueue.Count > 0)
{
    var NAMEIDYOB = MyQueue.Dequeue();
    Console.WriteLine($"[Console] {NAMEIDYOB}");
    Console.WriteLine($"[Console] {NAMEIDYOB.Item1}"); // Expected to print Name
    Console.WriteLine($"[Console] {NAMEIDYOB.Item2}"); // Expected to print ID
    Console.WriteLine($"[Console] {NAMEIDYOB.Item3}"); // Expected to print YOB
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

why not define the type of the queue?
`Queue<Tuple<string, int, int>> MyQueue = new Queue<Tuple<string, int, int>>();`

Then, you can use

```
      Console.WriteLine($"[Console] {NAMEIDYOB.Item1}"); // Expected to print Name
      Console.WriteLine($"[Console] {NAMEIDYOB.Item2}"); // Expected to print ID
      Console.WriteLine($"[Console] {NAMEIDYOB.Item3}"); // Expected to print YOB
```

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
var NAMEIDYOB = MyQueue.Dequeue();
```

with

```
Tuple<string, int, int> NAMEIDYOB = (Tuple<string, int, int>) MyQueue.Dequeue();
```

and to access the Tuple item 
`NAMEIDYOB.Item1` (item with capital case)
for example:

```
Console.WriteLine($"[Console] {NAMEIDYOB.Item1}"); // Expected to print Name
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to cast your `Dequeue()` as `Tuple<string, int, int>`.

Here is the complete working example:

```
var Name_ID_YOB = new List<Tuple<string, int, int>>(); // YOB is year of birth
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    Name_ID_YOB.Add(new Tuple<string, int, int>("Name", i, 1998 + i));
}
Queue MyQueue = new Queue();
foreach (var tuple in Name_ID_YOB)
{
    MyQueue.Enqueue(tuple);
}
int Total = MyQueue.Count; // Total Item In Queue
while (MyQueue.Count > 0)
{
    var NAMEIDYOB = MyQueue.Dequeue() as Tuple<string, int, int>;
    Console.WriteLine($"[Console] {NAMEIDYOB}");
    Console.WriteLine($"[Console] {NAMEIDYOB.Item1}"); // Expected to print Name
    Console.WriteLine($"[Console] {NAMEIDYOB.Item2}"); // Expected to print ID
    Console.WriteLine($"[Console] {NAMEIDYOB.Item3}"); // Expected to print YOB
}
Console.WriteLine("Dequeue Done");
Console.ReadLine();
```